# Resources for ASP.net VB Razor

Tags: html, razor

I am relatively new to ASP.Net MVC. 
I have experience using Html tags, however I have noticed that .vbhtml views use different expressions to render Html content such as:

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.[name])`
or
`@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller")) {`

I have tried looking all over the web (Google, Microsoft Documentation, StackOverflow, Blogs) however my findings have been limited and do not give me the necessary information to fully grasp this topic.

Does anybody have any good resources that helped them learn the language/syntax or any other documentation on using this language / markup? I understand the logic behind the MVC, however I am having trouble fully wrapping my mind around all the shortcuts, features and customizations that are available to me in Visual Studio.

I have been unable to find good centralized sources, instead I am kind of learning as I go with no main reference or resources to fall back on.

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome!  To improve your question, consider adding a sentence or two indicating what efforts you've taken to learn on your own.  For example, did you try using Google?  Did you try finding a book on the subject?  Your colleagues here appreciate knowing you've made some effort on your own before asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Brian, I have been developing for a couple weeks now and I have done plenty of searching, mainly online (google, Microsoft, stackOverflow , W3 Tutorials, youtube ...), to some avail. I learn more as I continue to implement more. However when faced with new obstacle in Visual Studio, I find it increasingly hard to get a larger picture on all the tools/methods I can use (and that are available to me) in order to solve my problem.

Comment: I was able to find a great resource:    
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/html-helpers, 

I was wondering if other know of similar resources and would be able to recommend ways that they became fluent in ASP.net MVC